# Reinitializing array of structs in function

Tags: c, struct

I am new to this site and sort of new to programming.

I am trying to declare an array of structs and then be able to initialize it in a function call. And then be able to reinitialize it with different values in Main and also be able to call the function to load different values. I am getting some compile errors that I need help with.

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX_NAMES 5

typedef struct name // Struct template
{
int   int_value;
char *string_value;
}Name;

void init_struct(struct name SETTINGS); // Function prototype

int main()
{
int i;

Name settings[MAX_NAMES];

for(i=0; i<=MAX_NAMES; i++) // Initializes struct
    {
    settings[i] = {1, "Test"};
    }

printf("Before function call:\n-------------\n");

for (i=0; i < MAX_NAMES; i++) // Prints struct
    printf("%i : int_value = %i, string_value = %s\n",
    i, settings[i].int_value, settings[i].string_value);

init_struct(settings[MAX_NAMES]); // Calls function to reinitalize struct

printf("\n\nAfter function call:\n-------------\n");

for (i=0; i < MAX_NAMES; i++) // Prints struct
    printf("%i : int_value = %i, string_value = %s\n",
    i, settings[i].int_value, settings[i].string_value);

return 0;
}
void init_struct(struct name SETTINGS)
{
int i;

for(i=0; i<=MAX_NAMES; i++) // Redefines struct
    {
    SETTINGS[i] = {{2, "Test2"}};
    }
}
```

Compile errors:

> In function 'main':
>   |20| error: expected expression before '{' token
>   In function 'init_struct':
>   |45| error: subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector
>   |45| error: expected expression before '{' token

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, with this:

```
Name settings[MAX_NAMES];

for(i=0; i<=MAX_NAMES; i++) // Initializes struct
    {
    settings[i] = {1, "Test"};
    }
```

You can only use that kind of initializer list when you're *defining* a struct, which you already did with `Name settings[MAX_NAMES]`. You're going to have to do `settings[i].int_value = 1;` and so on.

For your second problem, you declare a function that accepts a `struct name`, but you try to treat it as an array. You should change it to:

```
void init_struct(struct name * SETTINGS) {
    int i;

    for(i=0; i < MAX_NAMES; i++) {
        SETTINGS[i].int_value = 2;
        SETTINGS[i].string_value = "Test2";
    }
}
```

Note the change from `i <= MAX_NAMES` to `i < MAX_NAMES`. You'll need to make this change in your first `for` loop, too.

You'll also need to change `init_struct(settings[MAX_NAMES]);` to `init_struct(settings)` when you call that function.

Like so:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX_NAMES 5

typedef struct name             // Struct template
{
    int int_value;
    char *string_value;
} Name;

void init_struct(struct name *SETTINGS);        // Function prototype

int main() {
    int i;

    Name settings[MAX_NAMES];

    for (i = 0; i < MAX_NAMES; i++)     // Initializes struct
    {
        settings[i].int_value = 1;
        settings[i].string_value = "Test";
    }

    printf("Before function call:\n-------------\n");

    for (i = 0; i < MAX_NAMES; i++)     // Prints struct
        printf("%i : int_value = %i, string_value = %s\n",
               i, settings[i].int_value, settings[i].string_value);

    init_struct(settings);      // Calls function to reinitalize struct

    printf("\n\nAfter function call:\n-------------\n");

    for (i = 0; i < MAX_NAMES; i++)     // Prints struct
        printf("%i : int_value = %i, string_value = %s\n",
               i, settings[i].int_value, settings[i].string_value);

    return 0;
}

void init_struct(struct name *SETTINGS) {
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < MAX_NAMES; i++)     // Redefines struct
    {
        SETTINGS[i].int_value = 2;
        SETTINGS[i].string_value = "Test2";
    }
}
```

Output:

```
paul@local:~/src/c/scratch$ ./stu
Before function call:
-------------
0 : int_value = 1, string_value = Test
1 : int_value = 1, string_value = Test
2 : int_value = 1, string_value = Test
3 : int_value = 1, string_value = Test
4 : int_value = 1, string_value = Test


After function call:
-------------
0 : int_value = 2, string_value = Test2
1 : int_value = 2, string_value = Test2
2 : int_value = 2, string_value = Test2
3 : int_value = 2, string_value = Test2
4 : int_value = 2, string_value = Test2
paul@local:~/src/c/scratch$
```

Comment: Awesome: quick, clean, complete answer. Thanks a bunch!